# Operations on functions with different co-domains

Tags: functions, binary-operations

How are operations on functions with different co-domains defined?

> Let f: D1 -> C1 and g: D2 -> C2, and let (f + g): D -> C

What are sets D and C in terms of D1, D2, C1, C2?
Furthermore, is the addition of f and g only defined if f and g are real functions?

Comment: Addition is a lot more general than just applying to the real numbers. There are ways to make sense of addition functions with different codomains but it requires that you know something extra (e.g. they're part of a bigger space and addition is well-defined here).